# Antlr4 C# version: Where is Interpreter.SetCharPositionInLine in version 4.3

Tags: c#, antlr4

I have been using AnTLR 4 v1 since the beginning but now I am willing to change to v3, that is the latest stable version for C# target.

However, in my code I use `Interpreter.SetCharPositionInLine` method but I noticed that it doesn't exist in version 3.

What is the replacement for this method?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I figure out myself the answer. Using `Column` as a property is the solution.